# How to extract coefficients of a generating function like this one, using a computer?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, math-software

For example if we have the generating function $G (x) = (1 + x + ... + x^k)^{10}$ and we want to calculate the coefficient of $x^{3k}$:
What is the best way to go about it using Matlab or Mathematica?

Comment: Mathematica questions can be asked on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suppose that you could get different answers depending if the answerer is a Matlab or Mathematice user.

Comment: I don't mind using either

Comment: I am not a Matlab user. What I can tell you is that, using Mathematica, it is a very simple task. Hoping I am not mistaken, for your case, the seqquence would be $$\{120,2850,29050,182005,831204,3039400,9423040,25717285\}$$

Comment: I'm looking for the coefficient of $x^{3k} $, a number dependant on $k$

Comment: This is what I wrote.

Comment: I mean a closed form $f (k) $

Answer (score 0):

You can write:
$\begin{align*}
(1 + z + \dotsb + z^k)^{10}
  &= \left( \frac{1 - z^{k + 1}}{1 - z} \right)^{10} \\
  &= (1 - z^{k + 1})^{10} \cdot (1 - z)^{-10} \\
  &= \left( \sum_{0 \le r \le 10} (-1)^r \binom{10}{r} z^r \right)
       \cdot \left( \sum_{s \ge 0} (-1)^s \binom{-10}{s} z^{k s} \right) \\
  &= \left( \sum_{0 \le r \le 10} (-1)^r \binom{10}{r} z^r \right)
       \cdot \left( \sum_{s \ge 0} \binom{10 + s - 1}{s - 1} z^{k s} \right) \\
  &= \sum_{r, s \ge 0} (-1)^r \binom{10}{r} \binom{10 + s - 1}{s - 1} z^{r + k s}
\end{align*}$

From this you wan to pick off coefficients such that $r + s k = 3 k$. This means
$r = 0, s = 3$, $r = k, s = 2$, $r = 2 k, s = 1$ or $r = 3 k, s = 0$.